# Converting existing project to Spring boot project in InelliJ

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea

I have an existing project. I need to make it a Spring boot based project and I am using IntelliJ CE.

What would be correct procedure for doing it?

Edit:
Project has no initial structure. It is a totally empty project. So no existing modules etc.

Comment: This question misses a description of your "existing project". How big is it? How is it structured, for example do you have independent modules at all? Does it use gradle, maven, or does it just rely on IDEA for building? Does it already use Spring, but just not Spring Boot? One valid option would be to let Spring Initializr generate a Spring Boot app, familiarize yourself with it and the add the features from your existing project. Plus the reference to your IDE isn't really relevant - it is the project that should be converted - IDEA or anyother IDE can make sense of it then.

Answer (score 0):

[Spring Boot](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/spring-boot.html) is an Ultimate feature, so first you would need to try/buy the **IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate**.

From there, you can [add Spring support](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/spring-support.html) to existing project modules or use the [Spring Initializr](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/spring-boot.html) wizard to select the necessary configuration when creating a new project or module.

Comment: I have added Spring Assistant plugin to community edition, This provides spring support.

Comment: The spring boot plugin only adds convenient features to your development, but it isn't required. You can write spring boot apps perfectly fine without the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

In your maven pom.xml or build.gradle file, I would add the spring boot starter dependency:

1. `spring-boot-starter` (the group id is `org.springframework.boot`)

If the application is a web application, I would also add the web starter `spring-boot-starter-web` also with the same group id (`org.springframework.boot`)

For convenient features, applying the spring boot plugin would help in creating a runnable jar with all required dependencies bundled called a fat jar.

A great tool I use is the [spring boot project generator](https://start.spring.io/). It allows you to configure the modules you want and create a project template.

Comment: You know what, I wasn't able to open initializer from company's internet due to some security issues, the above link took me there ! :) thanks cheers, this answer helps ! Better to create spring boot application from init tool

Answer (score -1):

**Spring Boot requires IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate**. If you want to use IntelliJ CE, please create a project using [Spring Initilizer](https://start.spring.io/) then import the same to your IntelliJ CE (File -> Open -> Choose the project root folder). After you import the project, wait for some time so that IntelliJ can download the dependency and build your project. You can check from (Build -> Build your project). Then find the main class of spring boot and run it using the *green play button*